# What is the leading (most popular) account of intelligence amongst philosophers and/or artificial intelligence researchers?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, intelligence

I'm aware that AI systems are typically considered to be 'systems which act logically', but this is just a workable definition. I'm looking for something akin to a theory of intelligence. Something which (at least attempts) to provide a clear explanation of what Intelligence is, and how it functions.

Comment: you might ask on psychology stackexchange :) aside from that, this has come up before!

Comment: Still no agreement on what "intelligence" means in sight, whether in philosophy or AI. Best not to talk about "intelligence" in general, because it seems meaningless.

Comment: If acting logically doesn't count as intelligence as our intuition argues for, what else can complete it as intelligence apart from some integrated form of super rationality?...

Comment: @DoubleKnot https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligence for an overview of various takes on what "intelligence" could be defined to be.